# Using appsettings.json configuration in EF Context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I should point out I'm new to .NET...

I have the following appsettings.json file:

```json
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "MyContext": "Host=localhost;Database=test;Username=user;Password=''"
    }
}
```

In the MyContext.cs file I want to read the connection string from the appsettings.json config:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace My.Models
{
  public partial class MyContext : DbContext
  {

  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count);
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
  optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyContext"].ConnectionString);
    }
  }
}
```

But `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyContext"].ConnectionString` is null, any ideas why?

I'm using the config file successfully in Startup.cs via `Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext")`, but here I want to read the connection string from this config for situations outside of the ASP.NET application (i.e. in EF migrations I want to do `using var db = new MyContext();`), but have no idea why the above is returning null.

Is ConfigurationManager not reading from my appsettings.json file? Not sure how to tell, as `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count` returns 1, so I'm pretty confused. Is there anything obviously wrong someone can see?

I'm using .NET Core 5 and EF Core version 5

Comment: How do you run your migrations?

Comment: @GuruStron dotnet ef database update

Comment: rant: i wouldn't even need this if the migrationBuilder allowed me to get data i just inserted...

Comment: Do you have full repro? When running `dotnet ef database update` you can add start up project, which to use when running migration. Also can you elaborate on "migrationBuilder allowed me to get data i just inserted." - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Which type of project are you using? If you're using an API or a Worker you can use Dependency Injection to feed create your `DbContext` and, in this case, you don't need to bring anything related to `IConfiguration` into your EF Core context

Also any reason to especifically read during the DBContext creation? Usually the recomendation on a project with a Startup.cs is to let EFCore inject a `DBContext` for you and, there, you can grab a Connection String and have it as a parameter for dependency injection

Comment: @GuruStron i want to create seed data in my migration, not in the seed functionality itself because i want it to persist. That data is relational, so if the migration allowed me to get the data i just inserted i wouldn't even need to ask this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the common way to define connection string in ef core is

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(@"Host=localhost;Database=test;Username=user;Password=password");
}
```

You can access to IConfiguration manually:

1. install this packages into ef project

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
```

2. build the IConfiguration

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    }
```

if your Ef core  is in a special project, you will have to copy appsetings.json to this project

if you have  a problem to find appsetings folder you can define a path directly

```
// .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
   .AddJsonFile(@"C:\....\appsettings.json")
```

Comment: yes, unfortunately i think this is the only way to do it using configuration files...I am looking into creating secrets instead.

Comment: Great, even that gives an error: A named connection string was used, but the name 'ConnectionStrings:MyContext' was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850912 for more information.

I don't understand how .NET is so popular...

Comment: went with this solution in the end, thanks

Comment: I got this error: "The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was 'root\Repository\bin\Debug\net8.0\appsettings.json'. The problem was that the appsettings file was not copied to the bin folder. To accomplish this, you can add the following to your csproj file:
  <ItemGroup>
   <None Update="appsettings.json">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </None>
  </ItemGroup>

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're running either an API or a Blazor/Razor application since you mentioned a `Startup.cs` file :)

The recommendation ([official docs about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0#register-the-schoolcontext)), in this case, is to use Entity Framework's own libraries to setup your `MyContext` within `Startup.ConfigureServices`. There you'll have access to both the `ConnectionStrings` within your application's `IConfiguration` and to extension methods that allow you to register a `DbContext` with a specific connection string.

It'll probably look something like this, just adapt from my call to `Sqlite` into whatever Database driver you're using:

```cs
public class Startup 
{
  Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
  {
    _configuration = configuration;
  }

  void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
  {
    // Other dependencies go here
    string connString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext");
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlite(connString));
    // Other dependencies, et cetera
  }
}
```

This allows you to keep the Configuration logic from "leaking" into your "Model" namespace, thus your `MyContext` concern is just related to persistence of data and not accessing system files and environment variables.

In order to *use* an Instance of `MyContext` on a Controller or anything else created by .NET's dependency injection system all you need to do is *ask for it within a class' constructor*, like:

```cs
public class MyAwesomeController : ControllerBase
{
  private readonly MyContext _context;

  // This tells .NET to inject an instance of MyContext into your controller
  public MyAwesomeController(MyContext context) 
  {
    _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
  }

  // Now all you gotta do is actually use that instance - no matter where it's connecting to
  [HttpGet]
  public Task ListEverything() => _context.MySet.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not having issues using it in the app itself, but using the context in the app AND migrations. The app will read the config, the migrations will not.

Comment: fair enough, you're running your migrations from a different project then?

That's a downside of EFCore - it's pretty straightforward when you want to have everything in a single place but as you split into different projects it gets a tad tricky. IIRC you'd need to create some kind of "ContextBuilder" in the project you use to run the migrations in order to read the ConnectionString either from the command line (as an argument to `dotnet ef database update` and other commands) or from an AppSettings.

Glad that the previous answer worked to get you unblocked tho! :D